# unable to access /login route in express using typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am working on a demo project using typescript and express where I stuck at a point, unable to understand it's cause.

I am following https://itnext.io/building-restful-web-apis-with-node-js-express-mongodb-and-typescript-part-2-98c34e3513a2 blog to make this demo project. I have completed two parts of the series and got the issue where I am unable to access "/login" route (not able to send any request) and others routes are working fine. I have tried code of the other routes as well for this too and I don't find any useful material on google about it or I am a nerd don't know how to search.

Anyway, Here is some part of the code for my routes.js where I am having trouble

```
app.post('/login',(req: Request, res: Response) => {
        return res.status(200).send({
            message: "Bad Request"
        })
    })
    .post((req: Request, res: Response) => {        
        return res.status(200).send({
            message: 'POST request successfulll!!!!'
        })
    })
```

this is the code which is similar to the above code which is working fine.

```
app.route('/contact')
    .get(this.contactController.getContacts)      
    // POST endpoint
    .post((req: Request, res: Response) => {   
    // Create new contact         
        res.status(200).send({
            message: 'POST request successfulll!!!!'
        })
    })
```

Please let me know if need other parts of the code.

**Note:** I have tried to add and remove return statements but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using route package so instead of using app.post('/login') use app.route('/login'):

`app.route('/login')(req: Request, res: Response) => {
        return res.status(200).send({
            message: "Bad Request"
        })
    })
    .post((req: Request, res: Response) => {

        return res.status(200).send({
            message: 'POST request successfulll!!!!'
        })
    })`

Comment: Initially I tried the same format as you have posted, both works the same way for me

Comment: are you using a separate js file for routes or you are using a single file only?

Comment: I am using single file for routes